# Read crontab from remote machine

Tags: ssh, permissions, cron, sftp

I need to read the crontab file of a shared user on a remote machine.

I cannot SSH directly to that user, but rather SSH to my private user and then run `sudo -iu <shared user>`, so I can't directly run `crontab -l`.
I have an SFTP connection to that user on the remote machine, but I can't read `/var/spool/cron/<user>` directly, due to lack of permissions for the directory `/var/spool/cron` (it seems that the `crontab` executable can get the permissions to that file because it has the `setuid` bit set).
SSH-ing to my user, then switching to the shared user and running `crontab -l` is not optimal.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try something like `ssh -t user@server sudo -u shareduser crontab -l` (as a single command)?

Comment: As I mentioned in the line before last, doing this is not optimal. The problem is not with the number of commands, but rather with the method: it requires a personal user's credentials in production code.

Comment: Then set up a dedicated user account for doing this.